# Using @DataJpaTest with multiple DataSource and custom repository implementation

Tags: spring-boot-test

I need your help, please.
I'm trying to setup the following repository test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataJpaTest
public class ErrorClassRepositoryCustomImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private ErrorClassRepository errorClassRepository;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
    }
}
```

The test fails with the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'path.to.repository.package.impl.ErrorClassRepositoryCustomImplTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'errorClassRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'path.to.repository.package.ErrorClassRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'path.to.repository.package.ErrorClassRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

The injection of the `ErrorClassRepository` works correctly while the application is running.
My application contains three datasources which are configured like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "path.to.repository.package",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
        transactionManagerRef = TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_TRANSACTION_MANAGER,
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile("test")
public class TestDatabaseConfig {

    public static final String BEAN_NAME_DATA_SOURCE = "myTestDataSource";
    public static final String PREFIX_DATASOURCE = "datasource.test";
    public static final String BEAN_NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = "myTestEntityManagerFactory";
    public static final String BEAN_NAME_TRANSACTION_MANAGER = "myTestTransactionManager";
    public static final String BEAN_NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER = "myTestEntityManager";
    public static final String NAME_PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "pu-test";
    protected static final String[] PACKAGE_CLASSES = {"path.to.entity.package", "path.to.repository.package"};

    public TestDatabaseConfig() {
    }

    @Bean(name = TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_DATA_SOURCE)
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = TestDatabaseConfig.PREFIX_DATASOURCE) 
    public DataSource testDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean testEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {

        return builder
                .dataSource(testDataSource())
                .packages(TestDatabaseConfig.PACKAGE_CLASSES)
                .persistenceUnit(TestDatabaseConfig.NAME_PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager testTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier(TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY) final EntityManagerFactory emf) {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER)
    public EntityManager testEntityManager(
            @Qualifier(TestDatabaseConfig.BEAN_NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY) final EntityManagerFactory emf) {

        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

Factory:

```
public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    public BaseRepositoryFactoryBean() {
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new ErrorClassCustomFactory(entityManager);
    }

    private static class ErrorClassCustomFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public ErrorClassCustomFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information) {
            Class<?> repositoryInterface = information.getRepositoryInterface();
            if (ErrorClassRepositoryCustom.class.isAssignableFrom(repositoryInterface)) {
                return new ErrorClassRepositoryCustomImpl<>((Class<T>) information.getDomainType(), entityManager);
            }

            return super.getTargetRepository(information, entityManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            Class<?> repositoryInterface = metadata.getRepositoryInterface();
            if (ErrorClassRepositoryCustom.class.isAssignableFrom(repositoryInterface)) {
                return ErrorClassRepositoryCustom.class;
            }
            return super.getRepositoryBaseClass(metadata);
        }
    }
}
```

BaseRepository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {    
}
```

ErrorClassRepository:

```
public interface ErrorClassRepository extends BaseRepository<ErrorClass, Integer>, 
        ErrorClassRepositoryCustom<ErrorClass, Integer>{


    public ErrorClass findErrorClassByName(String name);
}
```

ErrorClassRepositoryCustom:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ErrorClassRepositoryCustom<T, ID extends Serializable> extends BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    public List<ErrorClass> findEcHnHtByLocale(String locale);   

    public List<ErrorClass> findEcEnEtByLocale(String locale);       
}
```

BaseRepositoryImpl:

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }
}
```

ErrorClassRepositoryCustomImpl:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class ErrorClassRepositoryCustomImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID>
        implements ErrorClassRepositoryCustom<T, ID> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public ErrorClassRepositoryCustomImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<ErrorClass> findEcHnHtByLocale(String locale) {
        // some code
    }


    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<ErrorClass> findEcEnEtByLocale(String locale) {
       // some code
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring-Boot 1.4.5.RELEASE and junit-4.12

I hope you can help me.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding for your test class \@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
\@DataJpaTest \@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.ANY)
\@ComponentScan \@SpringBootTest(classes = { DbConfig1.class, DbConfig2.class })

Comment: @Justas Thanks for your reply. After adding the annotations I get the the following exception message while creating the `myTestEntityManagerManagerFactory`: `No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean` . Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try adding default constructors.